# How to mock SetupAdd for a hidden event handler?

Tags: c#, moq

Given the following two interfaces

```
public interface IState
{
    event EventHandler StateChanged;
}

public interface IState<TState> : IState
{
    new event EventHandler<TState> StateChanged;
}
```

And a test subject that has the property

```cs
public IState<int> MyState { get; set; }
```

I need to check that `MyState.StateChanged` was subscribed to, but subscribed to by casting as `IState` rather than `IState<int>`.

How do I call `MockMyState.SetupAdd(x => x.StateChanged......` but telling it to expect a subscription to the non-generic interface instead?

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) but there is not enough context provided.

Comment: The class that implements IState<> is forced to provide the implementation for both events.  That normally isn't necessary but the types of the events are not the same.  Which does mean that you cannot do what you want to do, you must use IState<> to find the correct event implementation back.  Very high odds that the original design is not correct.